# Where do I place block loot table in 1.14 data pack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm creating a loot table for some blocks in minecraft 1.14 snapshot, and would like to know where to place those loot tables within my data pack... just giving me the file directory lineup i.e World/datapacks/datapack/data/name/function is where my functions go, where would my loot tables go?

Comment: You should probably edit [your old question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/340987/minecraft-1-14-snapshot-loot-table-how-to) instead of just deleting it and asking a new one.

Comment: @Frank That could have caused confusion if people read the comments, and this question has very little to do with the original... I also gave upon getting an answer for the original.

Comment: Did you look at the wiki? If not, do that. If yes, what didn't work despite reading it?

Comment: I feel this is the same question as before, just worded differently.

Comment: @FabianRöling The wiki does not describe what I'm asking in this question for 1.14, only for 1.13, and the loot table I want is unique to 1.14

Comment: @Frank The previous question was basically asking for a full how to guide, this question is literally asking for the answer I am about to give (got in MC Forums)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS I got from MC Forums when I posted the same question:

> .minecraft\saves\[your world]\datapacks\[datapack name]\data\[namespace]\loot_tables\blocks\[json files]